# Can I maintain the accuracy of a large number after cube-rooting it and then re-cubing it?

Tags: ruby, decimal, bigdecimal

I'm trying to do a calculation with a large number `x`, where I take the cube root of it (`j = x**(1/3.0)`) and then re-cube it (`z = j**3`). `x` should be equal to `j`, and it is when using small numbers like 26 and then rounding, but for very large numbers I'm having problems with mantaining the accuracy:

```
1.9.3-p385 :119 > x = 34567898765434567898765677654125 ** 3
1.9.3-p385 :120 > x = BigDecimal.new(x)
1.9.3-p385 :121 > cube_root = x**(1/3.0) 
1.9.3-p385 :122 > recubed = cube_root**3
1.9.3-p385 :123 > recubed == x
 => false 
1.9.3-p385 :124 > recubed.to_i
=> 41306551989787317397975170279355443182356154696413548486992943670408047235040641261388609159478 
1.9.3-p385 :125 > x.to_i
=> 41306551989788217308443399821163722262582437385123598833127062833015560078766131667297533203125
```

If it's not possible to end up with a close approximate, is there a way to end up with a more accurate one where more of the most significant bits are the same?

Comment: I need to find a value that at least shares some amount of most significant bits with x when it's cubed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
cube_root = x ** (1 / 3.0)
```

To something like this

```
cube_root = x ** BigDecimal('0.' + '3' * 100)
```

Or

```
cube_root = x ** BigDecimal('1/3'.to_r, 100)
```

And you'll see the difference.

```
1.9.3p194 :203 > recubed.to_i
 => 41306551989788217308443399821163722262582437385123598833127062833015560078766131667297533203124 
1.9.3p194 :204 > x.to_i
 => 41306551989788217308443399821163722262582437385123598833127062833015560078766131667297533203125
```

And that is because `1 / 3.0` is a very not accurate thing.

Comment: That is MUCH more accurate! In ruby, it's BigDecimal.new('0.' + '3' * 100). Very cool bit of code you gave.

Comment: yes THANKS! And just so I understand what you did further, the accuracy is increased with the number of 3s after the decimal, right?

Comment: Instead of `BigDecimal.new('0.' + '3' * 100)` you can also pass a [`Rational`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Rational.html): `BigDecimal('1/3'.to_r, 100)` or with `bigdecimal/utils`: `'1/3'.to_r.to_d(100)`